# Symfony UserInterface is serializing the entire massive User entity

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, serialization

We implement `AdvancedUserInterface` to manage user authentication, but for some reason Symfony security is serializing the entire `User` entity instead of just the minimum required fields (e.g. `id`, `username`, `password`).

According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#the-data-model), we need to specify the exact fields that should be serialized (and then the rest of the fields will be ignored).

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
        ));
    }
}
```

But although we are doing that, Symfony security is ignoring this `serialize()` method and still serializing the ENTIRE entity. This breaks the sign in because the object becomes too big to serialize and store.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation of how it works in Symfony 5.4 and later https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session. However, they mention `SerializableInterface`, without any reference and had a hard time finding anything about it. Such an interface doesn't exist (PhpStorm is not able to find it). I assumed they probably mean https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php.

I solved this problem by implementing `\Serializable` interface in my `User` entity as follows:

```php
# App\Entity\User

public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'password' => $this->getPassword(),
        'email' => $this->getEmail(),
        'userIdentifier' => $this->getEmail(),
        'username' => $this->getUsername(),
        'salt' => $this->getSalt(),
        'roles' => $this->getRoles(),
        'enabled' => $this->isEnabled(),
    ]);
}

public function unserialize($data)
{
    $unserialized = unserialize($data);

    $this
        ->setId($unserialized['id'])
        ->setPassword($unserialized['password'])
        ->setEmail($unserialized['email'])
        ->setRoles($unserialized['roles'])
        ->setEnabled($unserialized['enabled']);
}
```

I no longer save unwanted relations or data. The session is now small. I also noticed a significant response time decrease = faster page load for logged-in users, especially admins.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently Symfony security uses `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken` and this has a custom method for serialize that adds more data into the session serialized User.

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(
        array(
            is_object($this->user) ? clone $this->user : $this->user,
            $this->authenticated,
            $this->roles,
            $this->attributes,
        )
    );
}
```

This adds `role` to the serialized object. But we have a custom role system that has associations with other entities (e.g. `Site`) which cause the fatal bloating of the `User` when it is serialized.

Comment: Chadwick, did you manage to fix it? I am facing the same issue and User entity is serialized into session with all kinds of other relation entities

Comment: @undefinedman we did find a solution (because things are working) but I don't recall what it was... I think we somehow removed the relationships (restructured our entities) so that they don't get associated. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I solved a problem similar to this using the Symfony serializer with groups. You can read more about this [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups).

The function that encodes the groups looks like:

```
 public static function encodeCategory($objects)
{
    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

    $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $defaultContext = [
        AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
            if(method_exists($object,'getName'))
                return $object->getName();
        },
    ];

    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext)];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers,$encoders);

    return $serializer->serialize($objects,'json',['groups' => 'category']);
}
```

A simple entities example is this:

```
class User 
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @Groups({"category"})
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    * @Groups({"category"})
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Type", inversedBy="users")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    * @Groups({"category"})
    */
    private $type;
}
```

And the Type entity:

```
class Type 
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @Groups({"category"})
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    * @Groups({"category"})
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="type")
    */
    private $users;
}
```

You can extend this for as many entities as you like, or create new groups. And now use the function:

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
return new JsonResponse($this->encodeCategory($users));
```

Before using groups, I tried the MaxDepth annotation, but it seems this has [some problems](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33466).

Answer (score 0):

The docs at https://symfony.com/doc/7.0/session.html#mariadb-mysql state that we can use `MEDIUMBLOB` instead of the default `BLOB` for the column `sess_data`.

> A BLOB column type (which is the one used by default by createTable())
> stores up to 64 kb. If the user session data exceeds this, an
> exception may be thrown or their session will be silently reset.
> Consider using a MEDIUMBLOB if you need more space.

You can do that by writing a migration (for migrations see https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html).